# Agrupar array de objetos de acordo com resultado de operação

Tags: javascript, array

Eu tenho um array de trabalhos, cada trabalho tem um ID e a determinada quantidade de horas para serem feitos. O que eu tenho que fazer é agrupar esses trabalhos, em grupos que não passem de 8 horas trabalhadas. Por exemplo, com o seguinte array

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    hrs: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    hrs: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    hrs: 6,
  },
];
```

O resultado, agrupado pelos ids, é

```
[[1,3], [2]]
```

A minha maior dificuldade aqui é que somar o obj de ID 1 com o obj de ID 2, dá um conjunto de trabalhos, já que as horas são menores do que 8, mas somando o ojb de ID 1 com o obj de ID 3, dá 8 horas exatas, então esse é o melhor grupo. Percorrer todo o array e verificar qual é a melhor soma de horas pra ser agrupado é o que não estou conseguindo transformar em código aqui.

Até agora, [o que eu consegui foi isso](https://repl.it/repls/RespectfulQuickFlashdrive#index.js), faço um reduce e primeiro tento filtrar os jobs já agrupados, para depois prosseguir. E aí que eu começo a me confundir, dá pra perceber a confusão pelo código. Tento criar grupos de somas e depois abstrair aquelas que fazer mais sentido, mas parece muito trabalhoso e complexo, acredito que exista outra forma de fazer.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem qual é o critério para definir qual é o _melhor_ grupo...

Comment: É aquele que mais se aproxima das 8 horas de trabalho, que é o limite para cada grupo. Criar um grupo com o obj ID 1 e o ID 3 é o melhor grupo porque serão exatamente 8hrs de trabalho, enquanto somar o id 1 com o id 2 dá 6 horas de trabalho, sobrando duas horas 'ociosas', já que não da pra juntar o outro job porque passaria de 8hrs

Comment: Vc sempre vai ter 3 itens no array?

Comment: Não, a quantidade de itens vai variar de acordo com o que estiver cadastrado no banco, Aí que pegou pra mim, criar algo que seja inteligente o suficiente pra percorrer um array de n indices e agrupar sempre da forma mais eficiente